# Use of % operator in pipleline

Tags: powershell

I ran across a Powershell script on the internet that uses the '%' operator in a way I hadn't seen before.

For the life of me I can find any documentation that describes what the '%' operator's purpose is in the script.

Here is a contrived example.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:windir | % { Write-Host $_.FullName }
```

Can anyone point me to documentation on this use of the '%' operator?

Comment: It's an alias for the ForEach-Object cmdlet. Try Get-Alias -Name %

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [this blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/01/02/powertip-find-all-of-the-one-letter-powershell-aliases/), use `Get-Alias ?` to see all the single-character aliases.

The most common are

- `%` - ForEach-Object
- `?` - Where-Object

If you're writing a script, it's better to use the full terms so that it is more readable for others (or even yourself in the future). PowerShell has a tab-complete feature; for instance, `for<tab><tab>` results in `ForEach-Object`.

Comment: Useful tip about using the full terms instead of the alias. The alias will definitely come in handy on the command line though.

Comment: Good point - I tweaked the answer to make that a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's an `Alias` of `ForEach-Object`. You can use the following snippet in order to check the `alias`:

```
Get-Alias | where-object {$_.Definition -eq 'Foreach-Object'}
```

This produces the following output:

```
Alias           % -> ForEach-Object                                                                                                                                                           
Alias           foreach -> ForEach-Object
```

And that means that `%` is an `alias` for `Foreach-Object`(`foreach` is only an `alias` for `Foreach-Object` in the pipeline, as pointed out by @EBGreen)

> The only documentation that I could fine about the subject is this one: https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html

Comment: Just be aware that `foreach` is only an alias for `ForEach-Object` in the pipeline. When it starts a line then it is a completely separate command.

Answer (score 0):

There percent operator is short hand for ForEach-Object (or ForEach). If you want documentation proof, try...

```
Get-Help %
```